# Is it possible to embed a SWF in a form using swfobject 2+ in IE6+?

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer, dom, swfobject

I've been having endless problems embedding a dynamically loaded SWF into a HTML Form within IE 6,7,8 using swfobject.embedSwf.

All the proposed manual workarounds for the problem involve creating a reference to the Object DOM element from the window object. For example:

```
window[id] = document.getElementById(id);
```

Where id is the id of the swf object dom element. In my case I cannot set `window[id]` to the swf object id because it hasn't been created yet!

The line in swfobject that's causing the javascript errors is:

```
el.outerHTML = '<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"' + att + '>' + par + '</object>';
```

As the SWF movie sets up its Javascript external interface it tries to access window[id]. Since this doesn't exist, it fails.

If I apply the workaround mentioned above and populate `window[id]` with the DOM element that's being replaced by embedSwf it still fails beacuse it's trying to call Flash specific methods on a div DOM element rather than an object DOM element.

I find it amazing that this problem hasn't been fixed since Flash 8 and IE6!

Answer (score 2):

i'm not sure where you're having a problem. ExternalInterface and SWFObject work in IE6/7/8 just fine. See this [example](http://pipwerks.com/lab/swfobject/ExternalInterface/2.0/dynamic.html) (explanations for the example are [here](http://pipwerks.com/lab/swfobject/ExternalInterface/2.0/index.html))

when you say 'embed a swf in a form', what exactly are you trying to do? if you're embedding the swf into a div, it shouldn't matter whether the div is in a form or anywhere else in the body.

here's an [example of a SWF in a form](http://pipwerks.com/lab/swfobject/ExternalInterface/2.0/dynamic-form.html)

as for window[id], that's a deprecated approach and should be replaced by document.getElementById(id). a lot of old Flash tutorials/documentation say to use window[id] when working with ExternalInterface, but that advice is safe to ignore now that every major browser supports the W3C standard document.getElementbyId. This includes IE6/7/8, Firefox, Safari/Webkit, Opera, etc.

As far as the element existing before trying to find it, that's a timing issue. SWFObject embeds the SWF at domready/onload, which means you shouldn't try to invoke ExternalInterface until after the SWF has loaded.  You can do this by placing whatever code you're writing in a domready function:

```
swfobject.addDomLoadEvent(function (){
  //safe to execute code on your embedded SWF in here
});
```

SWFObject 2.2 has a new callback feature that lets you invoke a function as soon as the SWF has been embedded. Bobby Van der Sluis has an [example you can 'view source' on](http://www.bobbyvandersluis.com/swfobject/testsuite_2_2/test_dynamic2.html). The [SWFObject API documentation](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api) covers its usage.

hope that helps

--philip